# How can I reduce AD LDAP filter

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am using one application through which I provide an LDAP filter to fetch some data from Microsoft AD.
The LDAP filter textbox is of a limited length and doesn't allow me to use a huge filter.

My Ldap filter has multiple membership checks.for instance:

```
(|(memberof=CN=Group1,OU=Users and Groups,OU=MyUsers,OU=abc,OU=us,DC=local,DC=com)
(memberof=CN=Group2,OU=qwe,OU=Users and Groups,OU=HQ,OU=xyz,OU=us,DC=local,DC=com)...and so on
```

Is there any way to reduce this filter? Like if I add some common attribute to all these users, then based on that attribute, can I search the users?

Comment: You don't need to. As long as `memberOf` is indexed there is no advantage.

Comment: If possible I would create an additional group that would handle access to your application and include all the required groups within that one. This way your filter could only check (transitive) membership of a single group.